# SML - changing the value of a tuple element in a list of tuples

Tags: sml

I've just started learning SML and I want to write a program which takes 2 int and a list of tuples, makes changes on them and then returns a list(BOXES is a list). List always has 2 tuples. In some if conditions I need to change the amount of an element in a tuple. So for example I define Xb1 and I gave it the amount of first element of the tuple ( #1 head ) and later I change the amount of Xb1 in the code(and return the list). But the problem is that this amount isn't changed. 
Here is the code:

```
fun MoveBoxL(Xw,Yw,boxes:(int * int)list) : BOXES =
let
val head = List.hd boxes
val tail = List.hd boxes
val Xb1= #1(head)
val Yb1 = #2(head)
val Xb2 = #1(tail)
val Yb2 = #2(tail)
in
if Yw=1 then boxes
else if head=(Xw,1) andalso Yw=2 then boxes
else if tail=(Xw,1) andalso Yw=2 then boxes
else if Yw=3 andalso head=(Xw,1) andalso tail=(Xw,2) then boxes
else if Yw=3 andalso tail=(Xw,1) andalso head=(Xw,2) then boxes
else if head=(Xw, Yw-2) andalso tail=(Xw, Yw-1) then (Yb1=Yb1-1 ; Yb2=Yb2-1 ; boxes)
else if head=(Xw, Yw-1) andalso tail=(Xw, Yw-2) then (Yb2=Yb2-1 ; Yb1=Yb1-1 ; boxes)
else if head=(Xw,Yw-1) then (Yb1=Yb1-1 ; boxes)
else if tail=(Xw,Yw-1) then (Yb2=Yb2-1 ; boxes)
else boxes
end;
```

[cpn tools picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2PU9.png)
what's wrong?

Comment: `(Yb1=Yb1-1 ; Yb2=Yb2-1 ; boxes)` makes little sense. It just returns `boxes`.  All of your clauses without exception return `boxes` unaltered. You are thinking imperatively. `boxes` doesn't change. Also `Yb1 = Yb1-1` is just an equality test. It returns the value false, which is then discarded. You seem to by trying to do some sort of `let ... in ... end` construct with `(Yb1=Yb1-1 ; Yb2=Yb2-1 ; boxes)`. In any event -- you should show the definition of `BOXES`. We shouldn't have to guess what it is.

Comment: So how can I change the amount of Yb1 and ... ? how can I increase or decrease the amount and then return the changed value?

Comment: Just directly return the value that you would want `boxes` to be in this case. I'm really not quite sure what that is, since I find the intentions of your code somewhat obscure.

Comment: It might help if you give some representative inputs and intended outputs. Illustrate what you hope `MoveBox` will do. What does it have to do with boxes and motion?

Comment: I'm working with cpn tools,modeling a game like sokoban in which a man is trying to move 2 boxes to a desired place and this function is used to move the box to left. So each time it takes the location of the worker(Xw,Yw) and location of boxes(as a list) as the inputs and decides whether box can move left or not. When the boxes returns unchanged it means they cannot move to the left and each time it changes,it means boxes can move so the values should change. The problem is that I don't know how to directly change the value of the tuples in the list.

Comment: You *don't* change the values of tuples in a list. Lists and tuples are immutable. You return a new list.

Comment: Ok now the question can be this: how can I return a new list with the values I want?

Comment: Could you edit your code to give actual examples of intended input and output?

Comment: I added a picture. As you see (Xw,Yw) binds to (5,5) I mean it becomes like this (Xw=5,Yw=5) and also the boxes places becomes this this: [(5,4),(7,4)] ... box1=(5,4) box2=(7,4) . The function MoveBoxL takes these values as inputs ==> MoveBoxL(5,5,[(5,4),(7,4)]) and it's output will be a list. since in this example worker cannot move the box, values of the list won't change and function will return [(5,4)(7,4)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what these rules for moving boxes are, but the following seems to capture your intent:

```
fun MoveBoxL(Xw,Yw,boxes:(int * int)list) =
let
   val [box1,box2] = boxes
   val (Xb1,Yb1) = box1
   val (Xb2,Yb2) = box2
in
   if Yw = 1 then boxes
   else if box1=(Xw,1) andalso Yw=2 then boxes
   else if box2=(Xw,1) andalso Yw=2 then boxes
   else if Yw=3 andalso box1=(Xw,1) andalso box2=(Xw,2) then boxes
   else if Yw=3 andalso box2=(Xw,1) andalso box1=(Xw,2) then boxes
   else if box1=(Xw, Yw-2) andalso box2=(Xw, Yw-1) then [(Xb1,Yb1-1),(Xb2,Yb2-1)]
   else if box1=(Xw, Yw-1) andalso box2=(Xw, Yw-2) then [(Xb1,Yb1-1),(Xb2,Yb2-1)]
   else if box1=(Xw,Yw-1) then [(Xb1,Yb1-1),box2]
   else if box2=(Xw,Yw-1) then [box1,(Xb2,Yb2-1)]
   else boxes
end;
```

I renamed your `head` and `tail` to be `box1` and `box2` respectively. (and fixed a bug of yours where you were giving the wrong value to `tail`) and used pattern matching to make the bindings easier to understand. More importantly, I replaced

```
(Yb1=Yb1-1 ; Yb2=Yb2-1 ; boxes)
```

by

```
[(Xb1,Yb1-1),(Xb2,Yb2-1)]
```

which is what I meant in the comments when I said that you should directly return what you want the new value to be.

It seems that the logic can be cleaned up by combining the clauses with have the same return value into single conditions using `orelse`.